# B2C RestfulProvider save entire response to outputClaim

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have an API that returns a list of strings:

```
[
    "Some string",
    "Some other string"
]
```

I need to consume this endpoint with a technical profile in Azure B2C.

How can i save the response to an OutputClaim?

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="{claimtype}" PartnerClaimType="<what to put here, if anything?>" />
</OutputClaims>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently it's not possible in Azure AD B2C to map a body made of a JSON array. Only fields from an flat object can be mapped to claims.